# How do I pull the month from text strings in this Twilio format 2019-08-22 06:12:58 MDT?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, date-conversion

I am using the Twilio log file to crunch some data and need to convert the Twilio format for dates into something that Google Sheets can recognize as a date so I can then extract what month the date is referring to. I think that first, the text string has to be converted to be a better format and then I can use one of Google Sheets functions to extra the month. Currently, this is the format in the log file:

"2019-08-22 06:12:58 MDT"

I used GoogleSheets `TIMEVALUE` and `TEXT` functions.

```
=TIMEVALUE(I2)
```

and

```
=text(I2,”mmmm”)
```

I get "Formula Parse Error"

Comment: avoid using `”` the correct ones are `"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timezone stamp is messing up the Google formulas for you.

So you may want to try getting rid of that with something like this:

```
=text(index(split(I2," "),,1),"mmmm")
```

The `split` function breaks up the logged time stamp into `2019-08-22 | 06:12:58 | MDT` across three columns.

And the `index` function then gets the just the first column - the date bit from there.

And then the `text` function gets the month name out of the date.

Comment: How can I use this to also strip out the last index?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you give me an example?

Comment: For instance making this 2019-08-22 | 06:12:58 | MDT become 2019-08-22 | 06:12:58.  Right now I'm just stripping the 3 characters but would like a better approach.

Comment: If you want the data across two columns, you could try `=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(split(I2," "),1,2)`

Comment: But if you want the whole thing in one cell and only want to remove the timezone (4 characters including the whitespace), you could try `=left(I2,len(EI2)-4)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
=TEXT(LEFT(A1, 10), "mmmm")
```

and in array it would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(LEFT(A1:A, 10), "mmmm"))
```

[image]